# MySQL Query is really need a long time to load and then get a timeout

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query which is for showing data list with paging and with sort order. The sort order have an "IN" query in tree to show the data more accurate.

Here is the code :

```
SELECT 
  s.ID id_sent, 
  SendingDateTime, 
  DestinationNumber, 
  TextDecoded, 
  UDH, 
  id_folder, 
  Status, 
  p.ID id_pbk, 
  Name, 
  Number
FROM 
  sentitems s LEFT JOIN pbk p 
    ON p.Number = s.DestinationNumber
WHERE 
  `id_folder` = 3
  AND `Status` IN ('SendingOK',  'SendingOKNoReport')
  AND SendingDateTime IN (
                            SELECT 
                              MAX(SendingDateTime) 
                            FROM sentitems
                            WHERE 
                              id_folder = '3'
                              AND `Status` IN ('SendingOK',  'SendingOKNoReport')
                            GROUP BY DestinationNumber
                         )
ORDER BY `SendingDateTime` DESC LIMIT $posisi,$batas
```

My problem is, when i have a lot of datas in sentitems table; ex 3000 datas, although i LIMIT for 20 datas to show. The page is really need a long time to load and then get a timeout.

My question is, is it possible to improve my query??
or is it any other way to show my datas result exactly the as same as with my query?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the slowdown is the IN statement where you are looking through the list of MAX(SendingDateTime). Instead you could try parsing down that list with another WHERE clause. So it would be something like:

```
SELECT 
  s.ID id_sent, 
  SendingDateTime, 
  DestinationNumber, 
  TextDecoded, 
  UDH, 
  id_folder, 
  Status, 
  p.ID id_pbk, 
  Name, 
  Number
FROM 
  sentitems s LEFT JOIN pbk p 
    ON p.Number = s.DestinationNumber
WHERE 
  `id_folder` = 3
  AND `Status` IN ('SendingOK',  'SendingOKNoReport')
  AND SendingDateTime = (
                            SELECT 
                            MAX(SendingDateTime) 
                            FROM sentitems si
                            WHERE 
                              si.id_folder = '3'
                            AND s.Destination = si.Destination
                              AND si.`Status` IN ('SendingOK',  'SendingOKNoReport')
                            GROUP BY DestinationNumber
                         )
ORDER BY `SendingDateTime` DESC LIMIT $posisi,$batas
```

Comment: query is work but the result is empty. what is the mean of "SELECT 1" in EXIST query??

Comment: woooowww it works.. currently the result is as same as my query..
and what amazing thing is the result query only took 0,5 sec!! compare to 5-7 sec..
thanks a lot man..

Answer (score 0):

this may work for you

```
SELECT s.ID id_sent, SendingDateTime, DestinationNumber, TextDecoded, UDH, id_folder, Status, p.ID id_pbk, Name, Number
                FROM sentitems s
                LEFT JOIN pbk p ON p.Number = s.DestinationNumber
                inner join
                (

                  SELECT MAX(SendingDateTime)  as maxSendingDateTime
                      FROM sentitems
                      WHERE id_folder = '3'
                      AND `Status` 
                      IN (
                          'SendingOK',  'SendingOKNoReport'
                      )
                      GROUP BY DestinationNumber
                ) c as c.maxSendingDateTime = maxSendingDateTime
                WHERE `id_folder` = 3
                AND `Status` 
                IN (
                    'SendingOK',  'SendingOKNoReport'
                )
                ORDER BY `SendingDateTime` DESC
                LIMIT $posisi,$batas;
```

Comment: i think MySQL doesn't support the WITH clause.
because i get an error

Comment: Ok I normally don't use mysql. Can you check please now?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as c.maxSendingDateTime = maxSendingDateTime WHERE `id_folder` =' at line 13